# Fetching Facebook Timeline posts using Facebook API

Tags: angularjs, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm facing following issues while fetching facebook user/pages/group timeline posts:

1. I'm not getting all information (photos urls, link, created_time, etc) in posts objects retrieved using [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/group/feed#read). Following is a sample response of this api:

> ```
> [
>     {
>         "message": "this is going to be real fun https://localhost.com/N1AyEvZp",
>         "story": "Rajveer Singh added photos to XYZ Photos in My-group.",
>         "updated_time": "2015-09-03T16:27:34+0000",
>         "id": "405944472923733_413853035466210"
>     },
>     {
>         "message": "this is going to be fun https://localhost.com/EJo1WvZp",
>         "story": "Rajveer Singh added photos to XYZ Photos in My-group.",
>         "updated_time": "2015-09-03T16:14:41+0000",
>         "id": "405944472923733_413848848799962"
>     },
>     {
>         "message": "this is going to be some real funhttps://localhost.com/VyVKdWga",
>         "story": "Rajveer Singh added photos to XYZ Photos in My-group.",
>         "updated_time": "2015-09-02T15:45:08+0000",
>         "id": "405944472923733_413582785493235"
>     }
> ]
> ```

This response is missing the photo urls, links, captions, etc from the posts. Is there any different api for fetching those informations ? Also, if I directly hit the one of the post object **/405944472923733_413582785493235** then I get following response:

> ```
> {
>   "created_time": "2015-09-02T15:45:07+0000",
>   "message": "this is going to be some real funhttps://localhost.com/VyVKdWga",
>   "story": "Rajveer Singh added photos to XYZ Photos in My-group.",
>   "id": "405944472923733_413582785493235"
> }
> ```

Though I get *created_time* in this response but *pictures, urls,* are still missing. I found [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/post) api deprecated. **Is there any different api which can give me all the info ?**

2. The above response is also missing comments and replies. On google search I found that we can get comments using **/405944472923733_413582785493235/comments** api but again that api doesn't mention the *exact comments count*. *Also, the api doesn't give all the comments in a single api call*. They have a pagination kind of thing. **Can anyone tell me how can I get exact count of comments, replies to comments, and retrieve all the comments in a single api call**. If we can't retrieve all the comments in a single go, then **how can we use pagination** ? I need to send all the comments related to a post to my front-end. with pagination, how can I achieve that ? **Do I need to store the previous/next urls somewhere in front-end ?** Following is a sample response of this:

> ```
> {
>     "data": [
>         {
>             "id": "[post_id]",
>             "from": {
>                 "name": "[name]",
>                 "id": "[id]"
>              },
>              "message": "[message]",
>              "created_time": "2011-01-23T02:36:23+0000"
>         },
>         {
>              "id": "[id]",
>              "from": {
>              "name": "[name]",
>                  "id": "[id]"
>              },
>             "message": "[message]",
>             "created_time": "2011-01-23T05:16:56+0000"
>         }
>     ],
>   "paging": {
>     "cursors": {
>       "after": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZFhKemIzSTZOREUzTVRJeE5qWTRORGN5Tmpnd09qRTBOREl3T0RRd09URT0=",
>       "before": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZFhKemIzSTZOREUzTVRFNU16RTRORGN5T1RFMU9qRTBOREl3T0RRd05qZz0="
>     },
>     "previous": "previousUrl",
>     "next": "nextUrl"
> }
> ```

3. How to get *count of all the likes and shares* of a post ? I simply want the count and doesn't want who actually likes/shared the post. How can I get that ? I found that using **/likes** gives a list of all those who liked the post but it doesn't give the count. Following is a sampple response of that:

> ```
> {
>   "data": [
>     {
>       "id": "824565440992306"
>     }
>   ],
>   "paging": {
>     "cursors": {
>       "after": "ODI0NTY1NDQwOTkyMzA2",
>       "before": "ODI0NTY1NDQwOTkyMzA2"
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

*General Information:*

- I'm using Node.js Javascript SDK for hitting FB APIs.
- I'm using correct access token, so that's not an issue for sure.
- I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619742/how-to-get-public-wall-posts-with-the-facebook-api) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791951/retrieve-facebook-post-comments-using-graph-api) but didn't get any help from them.

I need all the information related to wall posts on my back-end so that I can send all data to my front-end for proper rendering. This is a screenshot of my front-end and all the information which I need in front-end.

[image]

Can anyone please try to clear my doubts ?

Also, if there is any optimized way of fetching all this information, then please do suggest. Your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You have to specify the fields you want

Comment: @WizKid: Can you please share some example or appropriate documentation for same ? Thanks